# Numerical problems of computing exponential numbers (from Gaussian PDFs)

Tags: math, precision, gaussian, exponential, numerical-stability

I have a list of very small exponential values (for example `exp(n)`, with `n<-300`), which are generated from Gaussian PDFs.

I want to compute how much each of them is proportional to the sum, for example like the following python-like pseudo-code does:

```
s = 0  # sum of all values
for n in exponents:
    s += exp(n)

for n in exponents:
    k = exp(n)/s  # I want to compute k for each n
```

The problem is, since the values of `n` are all very small, the summation `s` turns out to be zero sometimes, and I'll get the division-by-zero error.

I know one thing I can do is to add a constant value (say 300) to all `n` to prevent underflow, but it'll cause overflow in other cases.

How can I solve this?

I don't know whether I've expressed myself clearly, if any of these doesn't make sense or any grammar mistakes, please correct me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already observed, you can do it by subtracting a constant value `m` from all `n`.

To avoid overflow, do not choose a fixed `m`, such as `m = - 300`. Instead, choose `m` to be the maximum of all `n`. Then every normalized exponential value will be at most `1`, hence the normalized sum will be at most the number of exponents, which should be reasonably small.